# Can't use image acquisition toolbox with my pc webcam in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have MATLAB 2014b and can't creat `videoinput` object.

The error message is :-

```
Error using videoinput (line 391) Undefined variable "videosource" or class 
"videosource.empty". >>
```

I am using this code: vid=videoinput('winvideo',1);
Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: What code are you using to produce this error?

Comment: vid=videoinput('winvideo',1);

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add additional information rather than reply in comments.